# runs if statement after else if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

My code firstly executes the "else if" statement because the "if" statement is not valid. But after it's done executing the "else if" statement it goes into the if statement which now is valid. How can I make it execute only one statement per turn? I mean the whole point with "if" and "elseif" statements is to initially choose the statement that is valid and stop running the code once that statement is executed.

```php
<?php
//mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql_host","mysql_user","mysql_password","mysql_database");

$email = $_POST["email"];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email='{$email}'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){

    $totalt2 = array();

    $totalt2[one] = 'already_exists';
    $totalt2[two] = 'already_exists';

    $encodedArray2 = array_map(utf8_encode, $totalt2);
    echo json_encode($encodedArray2);
    mysqli_close($con);
} else if(mysqli_num_rows($query) <1){

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES (?) ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    $totalt = array();

    $totalt[one] = 'newly_created';
    $totalt[two] = 'newly_created';
    $encodedArray = array_map(utf8_encode, $totalt);
    echo json_encode($encodedArray);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `else if` block of code runs and then the `if` block runs in the same script?  If that is what you are saying then something weird is happening because that is impossible.

Comment: How on earth is that even possible? :/

Comment: There's no way it can go back to the first `if` statement. That could only happen if this code were part of a loop.

Comment: You don't need `else if`, just `else`. If the number of rows is not greater than 0 then it must be 0, which is obviously less than 1.

Comment: maby u have some code that refresh the site after and then runs again with the if ?